Perfect crossing of two dashed lines
I want to plot two dashed lines crossed at (0,0).
But, I would like it to look perfect (more like
cross in the middle), not shifted in (0,0) as in
the code below.
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))

x = np.zeros(100)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

plt.plot(x, y, color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=5)
plt.plot(y, x, color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=5)


This post and this one seem useful, but you have to get the proportions right to end up with dashes that have the center at (0, 0). Looks like the dash cycle would always start with full dashes from (-10, 0) and (0, -10) onwards.

The dashed/dotted effect offset is a line style element and is not affected by the data, but rather by the size of the canvas.  You can see this by click-dragging a corner of the image window to resize it.  Unfortunately, there is no way to control the offset as far as I know.

Hacky way to do it is to split dataset in (0,0) and draw 4 separate half-lines that start in (0,0) instead of 2 lines going through it.
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))

x = np.zeros(50)
y1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
y2 = np.linspace(0, -10, 50)

plt.plot(x, y1, color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=5)
plt.plot(y1, x, color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=5)
plt.plot(x, y2, color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=5)
plt.plot(y2, x, color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=5)

plt.show()



hacky smart way ;)

If you wanted the first dash to be half the length of the others, you could set the linestyle to include an offset, e.g. linestyle=(2, (4, 1.5))

You can set the offset explicitly in linestyle. While there's probably a way to compute the correct offsets, for simple use-cases I'd suggest just fiddling with it until it looks right.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

plt.title("Offsets in dashed lines")
plt.show()

num_lines = 6
for i in range(num_lines):
    dash_pattern_tuple = mpl.rcParams[f'lines.dashed_pattern']  # (3.7, 1.6), meaning a 3.7pt line and a 1.6pt gap.
    cycle_pt_size = sum(dash_pattern_tuple)
    offset_fraction = i / num_lines
    offset_pt = cycle_pt_size * offset_fraction
    ax.plot((-1, 1), (i, i), linestyle=(offset_pt, (3.7, 1.6)))


Not recommended: Computing the correct offset.
There's probably a better way to do this, but the best approach I've got is this: Manually the pathlength from the start of the line to the origin, convert it to pt, and use that to determine the phase that the dashes need to be shifted by.
As near as I can tell, there's no way to get the pathlength along a line, but it's implemented for the markevery() function and I borrowed that.
This approach works even with curved lines, but you need to specify which data index you want to compute the offset for (origin_index)
This probably depends on backend. I've noticed that it's slightly off for small dash patterns, so something's not quite right in the math. Regardless, maybe somebody can polish it up.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))  # Make the lines bigger so it's more obvious.
fig.set_dpi(600)
ax = plt.gca()

xx = np.arange(-1, 1.1, 0.1)
yy = np.sin(xx * np.pi) * 0.1
horizontal = ax.plot(xx, yy)[0]
vertical = ax.plot(yy, xx)[0]
origin_index = 10  # This is (0, 0), and we want it to be centered in our dashes.

# Force a refresh of the ax transform after plotting our data.
print(ax.transData.transform([(0, 0)]))  # [[225. 198.]]
ax.set_xlim()
ax.set_ylim()
print(ax.transData.transform([(0, 0)]))  # [[922.5 891. ]]

def get_pathlength_px(line2d, ax, start_index=0, end_index=-1):
    path = line2d.get_path()
    verts = path.vertices
    ax_transform = ax.transData
    disp_coords = ax_transform.transform(verts)

    # Adapted from lines.py:_mark_every_path()
    delta = np.empty((len(disp_coords), 2))
    delta[0, :] = 0
    delta[1:, :] = disp_coords[1:, :] - disp_coords[:-1, :]
    pathlength = np.hypot(*delta.T).cumsum()
    # This is in px, but we need to specify
    return pathlength[end_index] - pathlength[start_index]

def get_pathlength_pt(line2d, ax, start_index=0, end_index=-1):
    dpi = plt.gcf().get_dpi()
    return get_pathlength_px(line2d, ax, start_index, end_index) / (dpi / 72)  # 72pt in an inch

dash_pattern_tuple = (10, 3)
cycle_pt_size = sum(dash_pattern_tuple)
midpoint_of_dash = dash_pattern_tuple[0] / 2

for line in [horizontal, vertical]:
    pathlength_to_origin = get_pathlength_pt(line, ax, end_index=origin_index)
    dash_offset_pt = midpoint_of_dash - (pathlength_to_origin % cycle_pt_size)
    line.set_linestyle((dash_offset_pt, dash_pattern_tuple))

plt.title("Offsets in dashed lines")
plt.show()


